# Return comments total count including where it was shared

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am calling the API to get the total count of comments for a page post but it only returns the comment count of the original comments that happened on the page.

Does anyone know how i can get the total number of comments for a post both on the page it was first published but also where it was shared?

Thanks

Comment: You could of course try and find the shared posts first - but you will need the Page Public Content Access feature approved for your app for this to be able to access shares on other pages, and you won’t be able to get any shares on user timelines, unless the sharing user had specifically granted your app permission to read their posts.

Comment: @CBroe i just want the aggregated measures. Facebook should have a metric for it in their API but can't seem to find it.

Comment: I don’t think that exists. You can check what https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v7.0/insights has to offer, but as far as I can see, there is no metric that specifically counts comments on their own.